# Interprocess Communication using ASP.NET 5/vNext and Mono

Tags: asp.net, wcf, mono, signalr, asp.net-core

I have an SPA application which uses a self-hosted signalR windows service to allow users to interact with industrial controllers. Communication with these controllers is maintained using another windows service. The two services communicate using WCF.

I'm investigating porting the system to Linux using Mono and ASP.Net 5/vNext, and implementing the signalR part directly in an ASP.Net 5 application. I'm unclear on how I would achieve communication between the ASP.Net application and the remaining windows service. It appears that only part of the WCF stack is implemented on Mono and the transport I am using - named pipes - is not.

Is interprocess communication on Mono a possibility? If not, is there any other way I could maintain a service-like (ie continuously running) process to provide communication between my SignalR layer and my physical controllers?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you choose a mutch more portable transport such as HTTP instead of named pipe ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is that suitable for interprocess communication on a single machine? I don't think it supports duplex communication - which I guess I can work around if necessary.

Comment: Sure it's support duplex channel, not so easy to setup but it's supported by HTTP